# awk string match from 2 columns

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file (file 1) which reads something like this:

```
2  test1
3  test2 
2  test3 
1  test1 
4  test2
```

And there is a master file (file2):

```
2    test1
3  test1
4         test1
2  test2
3 test2
4   test2
5 test2 
...
```

I want to print all the lines from file2 when there is match between column 1 and column 2 from file 1. I want to keep the random formatting of file 2 preserved.
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

try

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1 $2]=1 ; } NR>FNR { if ( $1 $2 in a ) print ;}'
```

where

- `NR==FNR` Number of Record == File Number of Record (we are in first file)
- `{ a[$1 $2]=1 ; }` store key (concatenation without space)
- `NR>FNR` (we are in second file)
- `if ( $1 $2 in a )` if index in present ...
- `print` print the line.

which give for you sample

```
2    test1
3 test2
4   test2
```

Comment: can be simplified to `awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1 $2] ; next} ( $1 $2 in a )'`

Comment: I didn't think of it, however I tried to use explicit code, which is easiest to explain. after poster get familiar with awk, he can procced with golfing code.

Comment: It would be better to apply something like `a[$1"-"$2]` since with plain `a[$1 $2]` , possible records `1 1test` and `11 test` will be treated as the same thing due to awk concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'n[$1][$2]++'   file1 file2
```

Assuming no duplicates in either files.

Comment: Minor nit: this breaks if there are duplicate lines in `file1`.  A possible fix: `awk 'n[$1][$2]++ && NR!=FNR' file1 file2`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura, You are right; thank you for pointing it and for the possible fix.

Comment: Actually, strike that.  It also breaks if there are duplicate lines in `file2`.

Comment: Thanks JJoao and Sato ! It works. Fortunately, there are no duplicates in either files :-)

Comment: @SatoKatsura, You are right again; I will keep the initial version because the complete fix would end up very similar to Archemar's answer.

Comment: Just for the record there is a small pitfall with this solution compared to Archemar solution. Using `a[$1][$2]++` except for conditional checking an array position will be created. If `file1` has 1M lines and `file2` has another 1M lines this method will create 2M array positions minus common entries - common positions.  In Archemar solution only `file1` is loaded in the memory (1M positions) . The check `($1 $2 in a)`  does not create array positions for `file2`. Small details, but in big files impact can be important.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, True, thank you, (I upvoted Archemar solution).  We are pointing basic directions. With Gigabytes everything  has to be reviewed. I used bi-dimensional arrays because "2 4test" and "24 test"  would be equal in Archemars's solution (there is other ways to avoid this minor issue)

Comment: By the way In the well known SO "grep benchmark"  both awk solutions worked ok and with similar timing results tested with some huge files that were built by fellows over there :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '@ARGV and $h{"@F"}++,next; print if $h{"@F"}' file1 file2
```

Output

```
2    test1
3 test2
4   test2
```